# read two columns from a text file and sort both columns in java

Tags: java, file, text

```
18 14
19 15
20 16
21 17
22 18
23 19
24 20
25 20
25 21

47 44
48 44
48 45
49 44

49 43
49 42
50 42
50 43
51 43
53 40
53 39
53 38
54 38
54 39
```

my work is i should read this input file, remove blank lines and sort the both columns
here my java code which tried to read the file and print out its values:
here i stored the integers in different arrays
the code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class read
 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String dir1=dis.readLine();
        File infile = new File(dir1);
        System.out.println("Enter output file name");
        DataInputStream dis2=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String dir3=dis.readLine();
        String path="E:/photos";
        String newpath=path + "/" +dir3;
        File outfile = new File(newpath);
        int newcount=0,newcount1=0;
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(infile);
        BufferedReader fr11= new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile);
        BufferedWriter bufferFileWriter  = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(infile);
        String[] outputArray1 = new String[31];
        String[] outputArray2 = new String[31];
        int i = 0;
               while (input.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                        String line = input.nextLine();
                        if(line.length() > 0)
                {
                        String[] columns = line.split(" ");
                        System.out.println("my first column : "+ columns[0] );
                        System.out.println("my second column : "+ columns[1] );
                        outputArray1[i] = columns[0];
                        outputArray2[i] = columns[1];
                        i++;
                }
                }
                String[][] temp = new String[2][];
                temp[0]= outputArray1;
                temp[1]= outputArray2;
               for (int k=0;k<2;k++)
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
System.out.println("new row"+k+"new col"+j+"value="+temp[k][j]);
        }
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            for (int m = 0; m< temp[0].length; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n< temp.length; n++) {
                    System.out.print(temp[n][m] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
                       fr.close();
                       fw.close();
                    bufferFileWriter.close();
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to sort there? You haven't even created an array of all inputs? And BTW, why are you using `DataInputStream` there, instead of `Scanner`?

Comment: How about `sort -n < in.file > out.file`?

Comment: ... and never use DataInputStream to read text.

Comment: here i am using datainput stream to read the file name only\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of my question is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readnew
 {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String dir1=dis.readLine();
        File infile = new File(dir1);
        System.out.println("Enter output file name");
        DataInputStream dis2=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        String dir3=dis.readLine();
        String path="E:/photos";
        String newpath=path + "/" +dir3;
        File outfile = new File(newpath);
        int newcount=0,newcount1=0;
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(infile);
        BufferedReader fr11= new BufferedReader(fr);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile);
        BufferedWriter bufferFileWriter  = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(infile);
        String[] outputArray1 = new String[31];
        String[] outputArray2 = new String[31];
        int i = 0;
               while (input.hasNextLine()) 
                {
                        String line = input.nextLine();
                        if(line.length() > 0)
                {
                        String[] columns = line.split(" ");
                        System.out.println("my first column : "+ columns[0] );
                        System.out.println("my second column : "+ columns[1] );
                        outputArray1[i] = columns[0];
                        outputArray2[i] = columns[1];
                        i++;
                }
                }
                String[][] temp = new String[2][];
                String[][] temp1 = new String[i][2];
                temp[0]= outputArray1;
                temp[1]= outputArray2;
               for (int k=0;k<2;k++)
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
System.out.println("new row"+k+"new col"+j+"value="+temp[k][j]);
        }
        if (temp.length > 0) {
            for (int m = 0; m< temp[0].length; m++) {
                for (int n = 0; n< temp.length; n++) {
                temp1[m][n]=temp[n][m];
                    System.out.print(temp[n][m] + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("transpose");
        for (int a=0;a<i;a++)
        for (int b=0;b<2;b++)
        {
        System.out.println("new row"+a+"new col"+b+"value="+temp1[a][b]);
        }
        System.out.println("sort");
    final Comparator<String[]> arrayComparator = new Comparator<String[]>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2)
        {
            return o1[1].compareTo(o2[1]);
        }
    };
    final Comparator<String[]> arrayComparator1 = new Comparator<String[]>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) 
        {
            return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        }
    };
     Arrays.sort(temp1, arrayComparator);
     Arrays.sort(temp1, arrayComparator1);
     for(int p=0; p<i; p++)
        {
            for(int q=0; q<2; q++) 
            {
                System.out.print(temp1[p][q]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

                       fr.close();
                       fw.close();
                    bufferFileWriter.close();
}
}
```

The output is:

```
18 14
18 14
19 15
19 15
20 16
20 16
21 17
21 17
22 18
22 18
22 18
22 18
23 19
23 19
23 19
23 19
24 20
24 20
24 20
25 20
25 20
25 20
25 21
25 21
25 21
26 21
26 21
26 21
27 21
27 21
27 21
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can go for this approach, Create a `List<Item>` where Item is a
>   type containing 2 Column values. (x1 and x2)
>
> Then write a `compareTo(Item o)` which compares the x1 values of the two
>   Item objects presented to it in compare, and if that gave a definite
>   answer, returned that answer.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private Integer int1;
    private Integer int2;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return int1 > (o.int1);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i have same keys with different values so i am not using hash map  my actual  input is:18 14
19 15
20 16
21 17
22 18
23 19
24 20
25 20
25 21
26 21
27 21
47 44
48 44
48 45
49 44
49 43
49 42
50 42
50 43
50 44
49 45
50 45
51 43
51 42
51 41
52 40
52 41
52 42
52 43
53 41
53 40
53 39
53 38
54 38
54 39

Answer (score 0):

The following may give you an idea of ​​what you could do. This example uses some features of Java 7. The sorting is `C1 ASC, C2 DESC` like SQL `ORDER BY`, where `C1` is the first column and `C2`, the second column.

```
public static class Row {
    public Row(String c1, String c2) {
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
    }
    String c1;
    String c2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        Path inputPath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();
        option = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            Path outputPath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toPath();
            sortAndSave(inputPath, outputPath);
        }
    }
}

public static void sortAndSave(Path inputPath, Path outputPath)
        throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inputPath,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split("\\s+");
        rows.add(new Row(array[0], array[1]));
    }
    Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<Row>() {
        public int compare(Row r1, Row r2) {
            // C1 ASC, C2 DESC
            if (r1.c1.compareTo(r2.c1) == 0) {
                return r2.c2.compareTo(r1.c2);
            }
            return r1.c1.compareTo(r2.c1);
        }
    });
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputPath,
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);) {
        for (Row row : rows) {
            out.println(row.c1 + " " + row.c2);
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

As you see, the comparator is used when calling the `sort()` method in the class `java.util.Collections`.

Output:

```
18 14
19 15
20 16
21 17
22 18
23 19
24 20
25 21
25 20
47 44
48 45
48 44
49 44
49 43
49 42
50 43
50 42
51 43
53 40
53 39
53 38
54 39
54 38
```

Comment: sir this is not working for me and the output is also showing incorrect results